# Chave Primária: HashMap ou Object Comum?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?

A minha dúvida é a seguinte...
Estou querendo utilizar HashMap como chave primária. Há algum problema? Ou devo utilizar Object?

OBS: Estou modelando o banco de dados, que será com MongoDB.

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Hashmap como chave primária? Qual seria a lógica disso?

Comment: Eu estava querendo utilizar uma chave primária composta, e como nunca utilizei, estou querendo saber se é possível e recomendado... Object seria a melhor opção?

Comment: Como seria a sua chave composta?

Comment: Ela teria dois atributos, o "tipo" da máquina e o "número" dela. Queria utilizar uma forma bem simples, sem criar um objeto.

Comment: Porque não usar 2 integer?

Comment: Eu pensei nisso... mas gostaria de "tentar" colocar uma chave composta. Será que há alguma forma simples? Senão, vou utilizar esses atributos

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode criar seu objeto com os campos normalmente e depois criar a chave composta com os campos que quiser. No seu caso, vc criaria "tipo" da máquina e "número" e depois anotaria os dois para criar a chave composta.

Sua classe poderia ser algo assim:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@IdClass(MaquinaID.class)
public class Maquina {

    @Id
    private Integer tipoMaquina;

    @Id
    private Integer numero;

    // [...]
}
```

Classe para a chave composta:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MaquinaID implements Serializable {
    private Integer tipoMaquina;
    private Integer numero;

    public MaquinaID() { }

    public MaquinaID(Integer tipoMaquina, Integer numero) {
        this.tipoMaquina = tipoMaquina;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    // getter e setter
}
```

Segue abaixo o link pra vc dar uma olhada mais detalhada e outras opções de como fazer uma chave composta:

https://receitasdecodigo.com.br/hibernate/chaves-compostas-com-hibernate

Eu não sei dizer como seria o HashMap no BD, mas acredito que não seja a melhor forma pra criar uma chave composta.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, de verdade! Você deu uma luz para mim! Fique com Deus!